# How do I display a Float value on a UILabel in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var Screen: UILabel!
var firstNumber = Float()
var secondNumber = Float()
var result = Float()
var operation = ""
var isTypingNumber = false
@IBAction func Number(sender: AnyObject) {
    isTypingNumber = false
    var number = sender.currentTitle
    if isTypingNumber == true {
        Screen.text = Screen.text! + number!!;
    } else {
        Screen.text = number!!;
    }
    isTypingNumber = true
}
@IBAction func Operation(sender: AnyObject) {
    operation = sender.currentTitle!!
    isTypingNumber = false
    firstNumber = Screen.text!.toInt()!
}
@IBAction func Equals(sender: AnyObject) {
    secondNumber = Screen.text!.toInt()!
    isTypingNumber = false
    if operation == "+" {
        result = firstNumber + secondNumber;
    } else if operation == "-" {
        result = firstNumber - secondNumber;
    } else if operation == "x" {
        result = firstNumber * secondNumber;
    } else if operation == "/" {
        result = firstNumber / secondNumber;
    }
    Screen.text = "\(result)"
}
@IBAction func Clear(sender: AnyObject) {
    firstNumber = 0
    secondNumber = 0
    result = 0
    Screen.text = "\(result)"
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

This is my code. I am always getting the errors 'Int' is not convertible to 'Float' on firstNumber = Screen.text!.toInt()! and secondNumber = Screen.text!.toInt()!
I am trying to display a float on a UILabel(Screen). How would I do it?
Can someone tell me how to work a float in UILabel. This is Swift.

Thanks,
Rohit

Comment: You are already displaying the float value in the label. You should not be trying to extract a float value _from_ a label; you should be preserving the float value in your data. The label is just a view; the float value is _model_.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are trying to assign an Int value to a variable of type `Float`. This is not allowed in swift. You can try

```
let floatValue = (label.text as NSString).floatValue
```

and to display the `floatValue` in a `UILabel`, you can use **string interpolation** in swift.

```
label.text = "\(floatValue)"
```

To convert an `Int` to a `Float` you can do

```
floatValue = Float(intValue)
```

Answer (score 1):

Issue is you declared `firstNumber` as Float, but you are assigning an Int value to that variable.

Change:

```
firstNumber = Screen.text!.toInt()!
```

to

```
firstNumber = (Screen.text! as NSString).floatValue
```

**Note:**
Similar applies to `secondNumber` also.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```
@IBAction var label:UILabel!
var a:Float=1938.22

override func viewDidLoad(){
   super.viewDidLoad()
   label.text="\(a)"
}
```